# Secure Checkout And Login Page Online

Tags: magento-1.7, ssl, secure

I'm looking for a way to only secure the essential parts of my store.

From looking into the site I presume that the login and checkout page are the only real pages that need to be secured.

Currently I have check use store front SSL and Admin SSL however my page load speeds have decreased to much that I need to change this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Enable Frontend SSL.**

SSL urls are used by default for only certain areas (like checkout and login) in Magento. All that is required is to fill in the SSL url fields of `System > Configuration > Web > Secure`:

[image]

Make sure to Enable the option for Frontend SSL. **A well-configured theme** will  have url links back to the CMS portion of Magento that break out of SSL. Routes that require SSL will auto-redirect if you try to access in a non-SSL secured manner.

**Another option:**

There are a few blog posts out there (see one below) that tell you how to configure or create your own module that sets certain routes to SSL-only without the SSL option enabled in the admin.

http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/secure-https-magento-shopping-cart/

Comment: Thanks @philwinkle. I see that I need to make a few changes to the template. Thanks for the quick response!