# Forms stop working after start using HTTPS

Tags: magento-1.9, forms, https

All forms of my store stopped working after base url(secure and insecure) was changed to use *https*.

E.g.:
Login stops on blank page *[base_url]/account/loginPost/referer/[form_key]*
OR
Reload the page and present no errors.

Through chrome inspector, I can see two requisitions, one using POST method and the other using GET method.

### [image]

[image]

Anyone know something about that?

Ps: cache disabled

Comment: check form action http:// or https://

Comment: All actions are https.

Comment: share me url and form action

Comment: I Updated the question with prtscrns

Comment: can you plz share your website url

Comment: Sorry, https://www.ajhotel.com.br

Comment: may be it's cache issue clear your cache session and the check

Comment: Cache is disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tons of search, found this post here:

[Frontend login not working in Chrome with https enabled (1.9)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/64063/frontend-login-not-working-in-chrome-with-https-enabled-1-9)

The 'solution' was: set the Cookie Lifetime to 0 in Backend, and(of course), clear browser cookies.

It seems to happens only in Chrome, 'cause through Firefox(the only other browser that I tested), it works normally.

Still searching for a best solution and more answers though.

Answer (score 0):

either your rewrites are incorrect, some template customizations or you modified controller in wrong way.
this page is working properly:

https://www.ajhotel.com.br/**index.php**/customer/account/create/

make sure your .htaccess file dont have any weird rewrite rules, also check if mod_rewrite is working properly.

try to disable rewrites in magento to debug this issue.

> Web > Search Engine Optimization > Use Web Server Rewrites

or enable it, just to be sure.

[image]

Comment: It was enabled, now I disable it and comment lines in .htaccess, doing some tests, but apparently it is something with the .htaccess rewrite. Could you suggest me any .htaccess file for magento https?

Comment: there is no need anything special.  this is default .htaccess file must work http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.9/.htaccess

Answer (score -1):

See your Configuration > General > Web > Secure section and cooke section to adjust settings.

In secure: Change to Use Secure URLs in Frontend to On
In Cookie: try with Use HTTP Only off

Comment: Did it, not has changed :/

Comment: Clear cookies and retry

Comment: Same thing. Also, don't know why, when go to  https://www.ajhotel.com.br/customer/account/, it add *referer/aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuYWpob3RlbC5jb20uYnIvY3VzdG9tZXIvYWNjb3VudC9pbmRleC8,/* to the url

Comment: Try to remove sid to url Admin == System == Configuration == Web == Session

Comment: It's already on 'no'

Comment: Cookie domain is empty ? Remove it

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Go to cookie section intitulée admin config

Comment: Look here.... For chance... http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6341/secure-checkout-and-login-page-online

Comment: My configs are the same.. Still don't know how to clear cookies through adminhtml, I will try with a php script.